# What can actually go wrong when defining global functions in a cpp file?

Tags: c++

On my project I often see people defining global functions in .cpp files, i.e functions that are not restricted to file scope, class scope or any particular namespace.

These are clearly local helper functions that the author only wanted to be able to access in that file.

I know this is bad practice and the solution is to restrict them to file scope either by using the `static` keyword or better yet use an anonymous namespace.

But my question is, if these functions are not declared in the header file, what can actually go wrong?

I would like to advise these people against this practice but I feel my argument would have more weight if I could clearly describe what could go wrong. Or even what what might already be going wrong that we are not aware of!

Thanks.

Comment: Never tried that, but I think if you define 2 functions with the same signatures in 2 different source files, you'll get an error when linking, probably some kind of "multiple definition of ...".

Comment: @KirilKirov Except if you use `extern` to declare a function.

Comment: It depends on the scale of the particular project. If it is a small utility with limited scope and few dependencies, then probably there's no need to be fanatic about namespace tidiness. But in a library, or in a large project, it is certainly intolerable. By the way, functions declared in global scope are not evil per se. We used to do that by necessity in the old ages when not every compiler supported namespaces. But we certainly gave the public function names prefixes that served as namespaces.

Comment: @KirilKirov. I tried it. And you do. In VS2012: `Error 1 error LNK2005: "void __cdecl myGlobalFunction(void)" (?myGlobalFunction@@YAXXZ) already defined in AnotherClass.obj`. Thanks

Comment: @user3467895 - thanks for informing me about the result :) It was useful to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One, you are cluttering the namespace. The result can be multiple definitions, i.e. linker errors, and programmers choosing awkward function names to circumvent this. Imagine one source file defining its `helper()` function, the next one a `my_helper()` because `helper()` resulted in an error, then a third a `other_helper()` and so on... in any case, the cleaner the namespace, the easier it becomes to understand what is actually going on.

Two, and this is an extension of the above, imagine a `helper( int x )` and a `helper( long y )`, and you can imagine the kind of ambiguity that could arise from this. If you are lucky (and using appropriate warning options), the compiler will warn you about these conditions, but you might end up calling a different function than what you expected.

Three, and this is from a maintainer's point of view, if you see a function that is `static` or declared in an anonymous namespace, you know that *you only have to check the current source file for calls to this function*. This makes refactorings *that* much easier. ("Does anyone actually *use* this exotic but buggy feature, or can I optimize it away?")

Comment: And how do these two source files have to be related for these linker errors to occur?

Comment: @user3467895: See Kiril's comment. As soon as you try to link them into a single binary.

Comment: On your second point, can you describe a situation where 'you might end up calling a different function than what you expected'. I tried it out in a test project and it compiled and linked fine and called the helper from the current file.

Comment: @user3467895: Trivial examples tend to have trivial solutions and workarounds, and are not very convincing. Things get tricky when you're looking at non-trivial setups, e.g. conversion constructors turning your integer into a `MyClass` instance implicitly. Global functions are not a problem *in themselves*, but they are the hallmark of untidy code, and can *lead* to problems. Usually *much* later on...

Comment: @user3467895 Re 2nd point: Existing code which calls `helper(long)`with an `int` argument will perhaps unexpectedly call the better matching `helper(int)` when that function is added to the global namespace. (This will require a visible declaration though, for example in a header. If both functions are defined and used in only one file declaring them static will change nothing to the better.)

Answer (score 0):

[Ulrich Drepper's paper on shared ELF libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) is relevant for you if you produce dynamically shared objects, usually shared libraries. I assume that some considerations also apply to applications which just are dynamically linked. The paper discusses the GNU tools but similar concerns will likely apply to other tool chains.

In short there may be build-time, load-time and run-time penalties for global objects and functions.

Build- and load-time penalties are rooted in the number of (string) comparisons needed to resolve dependencies which are not necessary for locally-defined symbols like file static functions and variables. Drepper discusses this at page 8 using the example of OpenOffice.

The reason for run-time penalties is ELF specifying that even locally-defined but global symbols could be replaced at run time with definitions in other objects. Therefore function code cannot be inlined and further optimized, even though it is visible at compile time; and the function call proper is more complicated than necessary, involving more indirections. See Drepper's paper, pp. 17 and 18.